# how to make complete os backup to create update.zip?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, stock-android, rom

how exactly can i create a update.zip file from  an android device that runs on android kitkat? i tried to backup using titanium backup but it needs root access. is there any way to backup the complete rom without rooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb` has a built-in backup command. See, eg, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225467/backing-up-android-device-using-adb) for details.